# How to configure aws cognito and ses in my spring boot(maven) application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

In my webapp(spring boot, maven) i want the functionality that when the user signs up they get a link in their mail by opening which their account will get activated. If the account is  not activated and user logs in, they will get a token for 12 hours i.e., if the user logs in at 12 PM and then logs out, and logs in again at 6PM the token expiration time left will be 6 hours. Also, i want to store user's detail in my database. How to do that? Can i get some basic configuration code atleast.

I tried watching many tutorials, reading many documentation.